# Moving a single vertex deforms the entire object

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am sure I hit some button or command by mistake. now when I'm trying to move a single vertex from object, it de-shapes the object instead of moving vertex and faces around it.
here is the screenshot

[image]
Arrow is showing the pixel that I am moving. object is a simple cylinder divided from center.

Comment: Did you try pressing `O`? This will enable/disable Proportional Editing

Comment: Please post it as answer and I'll vote, I'm struggling with it for an hour and can't figure it out what happened. also would you please tell me what command o is running (menu item)?

Comment: @AaA What do you mean? The 'o' key is enabling proportional editing, the gif in the answer on the duplicate shows this being enabled and disabled from the 3D view header.

Comment: The O key toggles [proportional editing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit). `Mesh` > `Proportional Editing`